# How to apply single theme to all webform in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

I want to create a theme or page layout which will be applied to all the existing and newly created webforms.
I want to divide page in 2 parts. In left part want to show webform description and in right part all the webform components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your custom template by using the preprocess hook:

```
function themeName_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__'. $vars['node']->type;
  }
}
```

And clear your cache, and create template "node--node-type.tpl.php".

If you want to customise form then please follow the below link

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/howto/theming-web-form